# ngx-mask v16.2.6 upgrade - Module '"ngx-mask"' has no exported member 'NgxMaskModule'

Tags: angular, ngx-mask

I recently upgraded ngx-mask to version 16.2.6, and after the upgrade, I'm facing an issue where the Angular compiler can't find NgxMaskModule exported from 'ngx-mask'.

The error message I'm receiving is:

```
ERROR in ./src/.....ts:2:10
TS2305: Module '"ngx-mask"' has no exported member 'NgxMaskModule'.
```

Here's how I'm importing NgxMaskModule in my Angular module:

```
import { NgxMaskModule } from 'ngx-mask';
```

I've checked the documentation and other resources, but couldn't find any breaking changes related to this.

Has anyone else faced this issue after upgrading? Is there a new way to import NgxMaskModule or have there been any changes in the recent versions of ngx-mask that I might have missed?

Comment: Try updating the package by - npm update ngx-mask

Answer (score 1):

Since you are migrating the *ngx-mask* library to the version greater than 15.0.0, you need to do some migration in importing the provider according to the [documentation (Quickstart if ngx-mask version >= 15.0.0 section)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask)

> Import ngx-mask directive, pipe and provide NgxMask providers with provideNgxMask function.

```
import { NgxMaskDirective, NgxMaskPipe, provideNgxMask } from 'ngx-mask';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgxMaskDirective,
    NgxMaskPipe
  ],
  providers: [
    provideNgxMask()
  ],
  ...
})
```

For the *ngx-mask* provider, use the `provideEnvironmentNgxMask` (default config options application level) or `provideNgxMask` (config options feature level) method.